# How to determine if a variable exists in Chicken Scheme?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

Is there a way in Chicken Scheme to determine at run-time if a variable is currently defined?

```
(let ((var 1))
 (print (is-defined? var))   ; #t

(print (is-defined? var))    ; #f
```

EDIT: XY problem.

I'm writing a macro that generates code. This generated code must call the macro in mutual recursion - having the macro simply call itself won't work. When the macro is recursively called, I need it to behave differently than when it is called initially. I would use a nested function, but uh....it's a macro.

Rough example:

```
(defmacro m (nested)
 (if nested
  BACKQUOTE(print "is nested")
  BACKQUOTE(m #t)
```

(yes, I know scheme doesn't use defmacro, but I'm coming from Common Lisp. Also I can't seem to put backquotes in here without it all going to hell.)

I don't want the INITIAL call of the macro to take an extra argument that only has meaning when called recursively. I want it to know by some other means.

Can I get the generated code to call a macro that is nested within the first macro and doesn't exist at the call site, maybe? For example, generating code that calls `(,other-macro)` instead of `(macro)`?

But that shouldn't work, because a macro isn't a first-class object like a function is...

Comment: This you should know at compile time/write time. XY? What are planning to do with it?

Comment: I have added details to my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you write recursive macros I get the impression that you have an macro expansion `(m a b ...)` that turns into a `(m-helper a (b ...))` that might turn into `(let (a ...) (m b ...))`. That is **not** directly recursive since you are turning code into code that just happens to contain a macro.

With `destructuring-bind` you really only need to keep track of two variables. One for `car` and one for `cdr` and with an implicit renaming macro the stuff not coming from the form is renamed and thus hygenic:

```
(define-syntax destructuring-bind
  (ir-macro-transformer
   (lambda (form inject compare?)
     (define (parse-structure structure expression optional? body)
       ;;actual magic happens here. Returns list structure with a mix of parts from structure as well as introduced variables and globals
       )

     (match form
       [(structure expression) . body ]
       `(let ((tmp ,expression))
          ,(parse-structure structure 'tmp #f body))))))
```

To check if something from input is the same symbol you use the supplied `compare?` procedure. eg. `(compare? expression '&optional)`.

Comment: This is true, the macro can take an optional argument.  Alternatively, with `let-syntax` you can create a macro that's locally visible. And you can call helper procedures from low-level macros: there's no reason a macro should call only other macros. Just remember to load their library with `use-for-syntax` or define them yourself in a `begin-for-syntax` form.  For inspiration, take a look at the implementation of the [matchable](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/matchable) egg, which does something very close to this.  And there's the [bindings](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/bindings) egg.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in general, because Scheme is lexically scoped. It doesn't make much sense to ask if a variable is defined if an referencing an undefined variable is an error.

For toplevel/global variables, you can use the [symbol-utils egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/symbol-utils#unbound) but it is probably not going to work as you expect, considering that global variables inside modules are also rewritten to be something else.

Perhaps if you can say what you're *really* trying to do, I can help you with an alternate solution.

Comment: I'm trying to write a `destructuring-bind` macro that supports keyword and optional parameters. For this, I need to recursively generate code. The recursive calls need to know if they are in keyword-mode. I can't use a nested method because it's a macro and has to recursively generate code that calls the macro again. It makes no sense for the macro to accept a mode parameter, because then I'd have to call it with a null argument in the first instance. What I need is a lexical binding that may or may not exist, and react accordingly.